# Regex search a sequence and stop at first ","

Tags: java, regex

i need some help with regex in the following case.
I'm reading a folder with multiple files like these ones A.AAA2000.XYZ or B.BBB2000.AY

I have to search in every file for a line(or lines) with a pattern like this:

CALL(or CALL-PROC or ENTER) $XX.whatever,whatever1,whatever2 and so on.
the XX.whatever can be another file in my folder or it doesn't even exist. What i need to do is see what files contain that pattern and in that pattern if those XX.whatever are files or don't exist and output the ones that don't exist. The problem is i have to stop at the first occurence of "," otherwise i get false results and i can't seem to get it to work properly. I did everything except getting rid of that ",". I attached some code and example below, please help if you can:

Example (as intended to work):

```
Searching file A.AAA2000.XYZ 
Found procedure(s): $XX.B.BBB.2000.AY,LALA,LALA1,LALA2


Searching file B.BBB.2000.AY
Found procedure(s): $XX.C.CCC.2000.XYZ,LALALA,LALALALA,LALALALA


Searching file C.CCC.2000.XYZ
ERROR: File doesn't exist or no procedures called


Procedures found: 
B.BBB.2000.AY
Procedures not found: 
C.CCC.2000.XYZ
```

Example2 (how it's working right now):

```
Searching file A.AAA2000.XYZ
Found procedure(s): #XX.B.BBB.2000.AY,LALA,LALA1,LALA2


Searching file B.BBB.2000.AY
Found procedure(s): #XX.C.CCC.2000.XYZ,LALALA,LALALALA,LALALALA


Searching file C.CCC.2000.XYZ
ERROR: File doesn't exist or no procedures called


...........................

...........................

...........................

Procedures found: 
XX.C.CCC.2000.XYZ,LALALA,LALALALA,LALALALALA        
Procedures not found: 
B.BBB.2000.AY,LALA,LALA1,LALA2
C.CCC.2000.XYZ,LALALA,LALALALA,LALALALA
```

Parts of code:

```
private static final String[] _keyWords = {"CALL-PROC", "CALL", "ENTER"};
private static final String _procedureRegex = ".* \\$PR\\..*";
private static final String _lineSkipper = "/REMARK";
private static final String _procedureNameFormat = "\\$PR\\..+";

 private static boolean CallsProcedure(String givenLine) 

    {for (String keyWord : _keyWords) {
        if (givenLine.contains(keyWord) && !givenLine.contains(_lineSkipper)) {
            Pattern procedurePattern = Pattern.compile(_procedureRegex);
            Matcher procedureMatcher = procedurePattern.matcher(givenLine);


            return procedureMatcher.find();
        }
    }
```

READING:

```
 private void ReadContent(File givenFile,
                         HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> whereToAddProcedures,
                         HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> whereToAddFiles) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Processing file " + givenFile.getAbsolutePath());
    BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(givenFile));
    String currentLine;


    while ((currentLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (CallsProcedure(currentLine)) {

            String CProc = currentLine.split("\\$PR\\.")[1];


            if (whereToAddProcedures.containsKey(CProc)) {

                System.out.println("Procedure " + CProc + " already exists, adding more paths.");

                whereToAddProcedures.get(CProc).add(givenFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Adding Procedure " + CProc);

                whereToAddProcedures.put(CProc,
                        new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(givenFile.getAbsolutePath())));
            }

            if (givenFile.getName().matches(_procedureNameFormat)) {
                if (whereToAddFiles.containsKey(givenFile.getAbsolutePath())) {
                    System.out.println("File " + givenFile.getName()
                            + " already has procedure calls, adding " + CProc);

                    whereToAddProcedures.get(givenFile.getName()).add(CProc);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Adding Procedure Call for " + CProc + " to "
                            + givenFile.getName());

                    whereToAddProcedures.put(givenFile.getName(),
                            new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(CProc)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fileReader.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the comma is a marker of the end of the pattern you can make it the last position of the regex, stoping the matching when a comma appear. Like this

```
_procedureRegex = ".* \\$PR\\.[^,]*";
```

Comment: I added the reading files part in my question aswell. I need to edit the _procedureNameFormat parameter aswell to get rid of the ",".
I did what you suggested but it doesn't find anything now, not even when just reading.

Comment: I changed the answer, you might want to try it now.

Comment: Program outputs the read files, some of them are properly outputted but some still contain "," and in the non-used procedures output, i still get the results with ",". Got no clue. Posting the whole code would help you more in finding a fix or should i procede by reanalyzing my code and finding maybe a different solution rather than the regex?

Comment: Did you change the _procedureNameFormat as well ? 
What I mean is, you need to make similar correction on that too. 
Like this:    

_procedureNameFormat = "\\$PR\\.[^.]+";

Comment: Yes, i made the corrections. Output is the same, that's why this is bugging me so much.